# Choosing how to pass parameters to a target bean/page using JSF

Tags: jsf

I have been using JSF for a few years now, but I still have doubts when it comes to deciding how to pass parameters to a target page/bean.

I do think this question is a bit complex, and that some may tell me to break it down into smaller questions. But, I also think that the answer to all of the questions bellow are related, and that it addresses the lack of intuitiveness when all you want JSF to do is: "Go to that page and pass this as a parameter".

1. First, how to decide between Forward and Redirect?
2. After that, how to choose between `h:commandLink`/`h:commandButton`, `h:link` or `h:outputLink`?
3. Then, combined with the option I choose above, should I use `f:param` or `f:setPropertyActionListener`? Will both properly pass parameters to the target bean, independently of its scope?
4. Finally, on the target bean/page, when should I use `f:viewParam`, or recover parameters from the request programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to answer your questions based on my own experience. Some of them are so open that more than one answer could fit.

**A page forward** is the way to go unless you explicitly require the browser url to be changed. A page forward is basically faster than a redirection as it requires less steps. **A page redirect** is required if you want to make your views bookmarkable.

Use `<h:commandLink />`/`<h:commandButton />` **only when you need to *POST*** the server. Later on, you'll be able to perform a page forward or a redirection depending on what the method returns. As an example:

```xhtml
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.processForm}" value="Submit" />
```

```java
public String processForm(){
    try{
        save();
        return "list";
    }
    catch(Excepcion e){
        addFacesMessage("Error saving");
        //Error saving the object, keep in the same view
        return null;
    }
}
```

Use `<h:link outcome="list" value="Go to list" />` for **pure page to page navigation** within the JSF application. You can use either page forward and redirect. Use `<f:param />` to pass view parameters.

`<h:outputLink value="www.stackoverflow.com" />` could be used **for external links** to other sites (not into your application). Use `<f:param />` to pass view parameters. I however prefer to use plain HTML with `<a href="www.stackoverflow.com" />` myself for this case.

As for passing parameters to action methods in *POST* requests, you've got several options. `f:setPropertyActionListener` was so popular in JSF 1.x, but if you're already at 2.x I would recommend you going with EL 2.2, which allows **method parameter declaration**. Being able to use it depends on the application server you're using, but even if not available you could import yourself. Then, you'll be able to do things like that:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.saveCar(currentCar)}" value="Save Car" />
```

Use it wherever you can, it'll make things just easier.

For the view parameters, use `<f:viewParam />` too. It's the standard JSF way of parsing the parameters from the GET request, so just let the framework do the retrieving work for you!

**See also:**

- [JSF 2 link, commandLink and outputLink example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-link-commandlink-and-outputlink-example/)
- [Using EL 2.2 with Tomcat 6.0.24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333605/using-el-2-2-with-tomcat-6-0-24)
- [What is the difference between redirect and navigation/forward and when to use what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277366/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-navigation-forward-and-when-to-use-w)

Comment: What if you were going to forward from page A to page B, and both pages uses different beans. Would you use method parameter? If yes, calling a method on bean A or B? Or, would you use `f:setPropertyActionListener` and don't even call a method at all? Or, would you call a method and set parameters programmatically? Would you please update your answer with that information?

Comment: @RinaldoPJr you're misunderstanding the JSF cycle. One thing is to pass parameters to a view method which is actually tied to the current view. That's done by a POST request and is described in my answer. What you're asking for is how to pass parameters when performing a navigation. That could be perform in several ways, but what I recommend is to use `f:viewParam` in order to parse plain GET parameters. Have a look at [this](http://bit.ly/1fZDGLa). You could of course mix both utilities performing a POST with a parameter and sending the same parameter in your outcome. That's plain HTTP matter

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in my last comment that I was trying to think of something that wasn't GET parameters. You said, when performing a navigation, "That could be perform in several ways", would you mind to expand your answer with an explanation/examples?

Comment: [Here you have](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21277621/1199132) an answer I gave some time ago about the flash scope. This allows you passing non-view parameters through views.