# Navigate to other view passing a parameter

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, navigation, viewparams

My current environment is JRE 1.7, JSF 2.2, Eclipse Luna. In a certain page (`entity_index.xhtml`) of my application I have the following (PrimeFaces) button:

```
<p:commandButton value="Details" action="entity_details"
                 ajax="false" onclick="this.form.target='_blank'">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{entity.id}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

The idea is to provide a button so the user can click it and some details on the current entity will be shown in another browser tab (page `entity_details.xhtml`). This is one button of many, so the `entity_index.xhtml` page shows many instances of Entity, each one with a details button.

The button works in the sense a new tab opens and that the correct page (`entity_details.xhtml`) is shown, but the entity id never gets to the bean that handles the detail page (`EntityDetailsMB`). The details page is as follows:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:dsi="http://www.cce.ufpr.br"
    template="/private/template/sbadmin.xhtml">
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{entityDetailsMB.id}"/>
</f:metadata>

<ui:define name="content">
<h2 class="page-header">#{entityDetailsMB.entity.name}</h2>
<h:form id="form">
...
</ui:composition>
```

Notice that there is a `<f:metadata/>` element dedicated to capture the parameter sent from the index page and forward it to the `id` property in `EntityDetailsMB`, where there is the following:

```
public Entity getEntity() {
    return entityById(id);
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long value) {
    id = value;
}
```

Because the `setId()` method is never called, `getEntity()` always returns `null`.

What is missing to make it to work?

Comment: did you try to make an outcome and add a param to get data from the first JSF Page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`p:commandButton` performs a *POST* request. You want simply to *GET* a view with your entity detail, not to *POST* the server, so you need a `h:link`:

```xhtml
<h:link value="Details" outcome="entity_details" target="_blank">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{entity.id}" />
</h:link>
```

Then, the `f:viewParam` in the destination page will be able to process the url parameter:

```xhtml
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{entityDetailsMB.id}"/>
    <f:viewAction action="#{entityDetailsMB.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

Use a `f:viewAction` to initialize your entity instead of doing it in a getter, [which is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times):

```java
public void init(){
    entity = entityById(id);
}
```

**See also:**

- [Choosing how to pass parameters to a target bean/page using JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256053/choosing-how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-target-bean-page-using-jsf)
- [When to use f:viewAction / preRenderView versus PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844526/when-to-use-fviewaction-prerenderview-versus-postconstruct)