# send object from @ViewScoped controller to other @ViewScoped controller after clicking on <h:commandButton> in CDI Bean JSF2.0

Tags: jsf, cdi, managed-bean

Please I want to get an object from controller which is in @ViewScoped scope in other controller with same scope. How could I achieve this knowing that Im not in a redirection case i want get it after clicking an action button.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just pass it as a request parameter from view to view: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39000013/1199132

Answer (score 0):

You can use the session map of the faces context as shown below:

```
//In view Scope 1 pass the object 
String strObj = "Use your object here";
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
ec.getSessionMap().put("obj", strObj );

//In view scope 2 get the object
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
String strObj = (String)ec.getSessionMap().get("strObj ");
```

Comment: not working :( . the object still null in the other Bean . I tried to display it in the @PostConstructor it is null

Comment: It works the object is null, try using your own object in place of object.

Comment: I just updated the code, try again you will confirm it works.